# Is count() being used correctly for my query?

Tags: sql, t-sql

*Find all teams that only won 1 game in tourney #3 (1 column, 4 rows)*

My thought process to create this query is that I need to count (WonGame)s for each Team. And that that number cannot be has to equal 1. But When I run my query I get no results (I should get 4 teams).

Experimenting with my query I changed the equals to a greater than and that returned 8 results. So I don't understand why equals 1 returns no results.

Also I checked my Data and there is indeed 4 teams that one only one game during Tournament #3.

```
select Teams.TeamName
from Teams
join Bowlers on Teams.TeamID = Bowlers.TeamID
join Bowler_Scores on Bowlers.BowlerID = Bowler_Scores.BowlerID
join Match_Games on Bowler_Scores.GameNumber = Match_Games.GameNumber
join Tourney_Matches on Match_Games.MatchID = Tourney_Matches.MatchID
where Tourney_Matches.TourneyID = 3
group by Teams.TeamName
having count(Bowler_Scores.WonGame) = 1;
```

[Bowling League DB Structure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV2B9WQKueUXJhNs1A_HonxbmDIJa8Wt/view)

[Bowling League Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xl3Dn-7-vLKClfWQNBzjACO2N948JxHi/view)

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Here is a link to my sql files to create the DB and fill it with data. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xl3Dn-7-vLKClfWQNBzjACO2N948JxHi/view?usp=sharing        https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SV2B9WQKueUXJhNs1A_HonxbmDIJa8Wt/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram seems to indicate that the relationship between Match_Games and Bowler_Scores is on BOTH of MatchID and GameNumber

If you change your JOIN conditions to be both columns

```
join Match_Games on Bowler_Scores.GameNumber = Match_Games.GameNumber and Bowler_Scores.MatchID = Match_Games.MatchID
```

Then you might get the required answer.

Comment: No it still returns no results for my query.

Comment: SELECT t.TeamName, COUNT(*)
    FROM Tourney_Matches tm
    JOIN Match_Games mg ON tm.MatchID = mg.MatchID
    JOIN Teams t ON mg.WinningTeamID = t.TeamID
    WHERE tm.TourneyID = 3
    GROUP BY t.TeamName
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1

Comment: What column should your query count? There isn't  Bowler_Scores included in your query

Comment: It is the formatting that the site applies -  it is `COUNT (  *  )` in both places.    When looking through your data, Bowler_Scores is n't required to get the teams that only won 1 game as you have the winning team for each Game in Match_Games

Comment: I used mg.WinningTeamID and It returned the desired result. Thanks for your help. Would you mine brief explaining what was wrong with my original query?

Comment: For one, you missed the additional column in the JOIN between Match_Games and Bowler_Scores which meant that each Game from the Match was being multiplied out in the JOIN - i.e. you'd get 3 rows where you should get 1.   Also, doing the COUNT would get the fact that there was always a row - for some it would be 0 and other it would be 1 but you are not distinguishing between them. SUM on the other hand only gets those that have a value of 1 included.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate on what your data really looks like.  However, it is doubtful that this expression:

```
having count(Bowler_Scores.WonGame) = 1;
```

does what you want.  This counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  Presumably, `WonGame` as some value such as "1" or "W" for the winner.  If the value were `1`, then the correct expression would be:

```
having sum(Bowler_Scores.WonGame) = 1
```

This is just speculation though without a better description of your data.

EDIT:

Based on the comment:

```
having sum(convert(int, Bowler_Scores.WonGame)) = 1
```

Comment: I cannot SUM(Bowler_Score.WonGame) because it is a bit value.

Comment: @Tomarik . . . Then convert it to an int.